# Decreased wifi speed with multiple AP's broadcasting on same SSID

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, dd-wrt

I purchased two D-Link Wireless N routers today and installed DD-WRT on both.

I put them on opposite ends of my house. One is acting at my Router and NAT as well as a Wifi AP. The other is hardwired via Cat-5 to the switch side of the NAT Router, and is acting as simply an AP.

I set both with identical SSID + encryption settings.

I've tried all sorts of different channel combinations or just leaving them set to Auto. However, no matter what, when both APs are on my connection drops to 300k a second or so. When only one has the wireless enabled, it works at a respectable speed.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Review the [guide](http://www.dd-wrt.ca/wiki/index.php/Wireless_Access_Point) and try channels #1 and #11.